# Stop NSComboBox from expanding to content size in a constraint based layout

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I have a little view which can be resized which has a constraint based layout:

[image: Happy view which can be scaled in either direction]

Unfortunately when a value is picked from a NSComboBox, the length of that string is pushing around my layout. Its hard to tell here because the images are scaled but if I had a string the width of the entire screen it would push it all the way. How do I stop this?

[image: Sad View]

Comment: What about setting up a width constraint?

Comment: If I set a width constraint then my entire view becomes fixed width. The controls width is the only thing that changes when when horizontally resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the combo box's Compression Resistance priority to be less than 490 (`NSLayoutPriorityDragThatCannotResizeWindow`). That makes it so that the autolayout system will prefer to make the combo box smaller than its intrinsic size rather than make the window bigger.